# python np.loadtxt() giving ValueError: invalid literal for float():

Tags: python

I am trying to create the following variable and keep getting the `"ValueError: invalid literal for float():"` error.

```
  pathsets=np.loadtxt('/Volumes/bk/old/6done/post/MAGlist.txt')
```

MAGlist.txt is of file names like: "070711_after_5mm_46dB_007_VARS"

whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

By default `np.loadtxt` uses a `dtype` (datatype) of `float` when reading data from a file, you must specify a different type in the call

```
pathsets=np.loadtxt('/Volumes/bk/old/6done/post/MAGlist.txt', dtype=str)
```

to get around this error